# Парсинг строки key.key2 в многомерный object

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, объекты, for

Как можно реализовать переобразование из одномерного обекта в многомерный?

```
{
 'key1.key2.key3':'test',
 'key1.key3':'value'
}
```

в такое

```
{
    key1:{
        key2:{
            key3:'test'
        },
        key3:'value'
    }
}
```

такое  делает nconf модуль npm  только с 'key1:key2' на  nodejs как повторить его возможности?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Наверное первым делом стоит получить оба объекта из массива:

```js
    function parse(key, value) {
     var split = key.split(".");
     var object = {};
     
     //object[split[0]] = (split.length > 1) ? parse(split.slice(1).join("."), value) : value;
     
     if(split.length > 1) {
      object[split[0]] = parse(split.slice(1).join("."), value);
     }
     else {
      object[split[0]] = value;
     }
     
     return object;
    }

    var json = {
     'key1.key2.key3':'test',
     'key1.key3':'value'
    };


    for(var key in json) {
      console.log(parse(key, json[key]));
    }
```

А дальше скрестить объекты [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```js
var json = {
 'key1.key2.key3':'test',
 'key1.key3':'value'
};

var objectMerge = [];

for(var key in json) {
 objectMerge.push(parse(key, json[key]));
}

console.log(merge(...objectMerge));

function merge() {
 var object = {};
 
 for(var i=0; i < arguments.length; i++) {
  for(var key in arguments[i]) {
   if(typeof arguments[i][key] == "string") {
    object[key] = arguments[i][key];
   }
   else {
    object[key] = Object.assign({}, object[key], merge(arguments[i][key]));
   }
  }
 }
 
 return object;
}


function parse(key, value) {
 var split = key.split(".");
 var object = {};
 
 //object[split[0]] = (split.length > 1) ? parse(split.slice(1).join("."), value) : value;
 
 if(split.length > 1) {
  object[split[0]] = parse(split.slice(1).join("."), value);
 }
 else {
  object[split[0]] = value;
 }
 
 return object;
}
```

Comment: большое спасибо